# Querying 3 tables using UNION only works on 2 of the tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay so I have three user tables separated intentionally. I have written some PHP to allow any user (Designer/Developer/Employer) to log in using a UNION query however this only works with the Developer and Employer tables. As soon as I add the Designer table to the query, it is impossible to log in. If I use just the Designer table in the query, that also works. Any ideas?

**This used to work but now doesn't (Developers, Employers *and* Designers**

```
$email = clean_string($db_server, $email); 
$password = clean_string($db_server, $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM connectdDB.developers WHERE developers.email='$email' UNION SELECT * FROM connectdDB.employers WHERE employers.email='$email' UNION SELECT * FROM connectdDB.designers WHERE designers.email='$email'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
```

**This works (Developers & Employers)**

```
$email = clean_string($db_server, $email); 
$password = clean_string($db_server, $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM connectdDB.developers WHERE developers.email='$email' UNION SELECT * FROM connectdDB.employers WHERE employers.email='$email'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
```

**This works (Just Designers)**

```
$email = clean_string($db_server, $email); 
$password = clean_string($db_server, $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM connectdDB.designers WHERE designers.email='$email'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
```

**Designers**

```
id  | firstname | lastname | email | password | jobtitle | age | experience | bio | speciality
--------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
```

**Developers**

```
id  | firstname | lastname | email | password | jobtitle | age | experience | bio | 
--------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------
```

**Employers**

```
id  | firstname | lastname | email | password | businessname | businesstype | businesswebsite | businessbio |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Use join on the emails

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more detail please?

Comment: Really?Developers adn Employers have different nr of columns and it works?

Comment: Sorry, yes Developers and Employer both have 9 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Designers` has 10 columns the others have 9 columns.`Union` requires the same number of columns,what you could do is specify the columns

```
SELECT col1,col2... FROM t1 UNION SELECT col1,col2... FROM t2
```

Use aliases to homogenize the column names.